# Привязка bindingNavigator ко всем dataGridView

Tags: c#

Можно ли привязать `bindingNavigator`  ко всем `dataGridView`? Все `dataGridView` находятся на одной форме и имеют один источник.

Answer (score 1):

`BindingNavigator` также как и `DataGridView` привязывается к `BindingSource`.

Поэтому, если `BindingSource` (читайте источник данных) у всех `DataGridView` общий, то при привязке к нему `BindingNavigator` автоматически привяжется ко всем `DataGridView`.

Comment: Как у BindingNavigator указать этот "источник данных"?

Comment: @Тимофей, это делается с помощью свойства `BindingSource`..